# Html classname attribute is appended with a space character

Tags: jquery, html

In my page I have a classname attribute with a tag. The classname is appended with a space character. I dont know where that space character is coming from? Where is it coming from?

I have the following code

```
if (collection[i].getAttribute("class") === "modified") {
                        var item = collection[i];
                        $(item).text("1");
                        editRowId = null;
                        $("#txtId").val("");
                        $("#txtName").val("");
                    }

$("#centerTable").append("<tr id='tableRow'><td id='rowid' class='hiddenColumn'>" + "-1" + "</td><td id='centerid'>" + centerid + "</td><td id='centerAddress'>" + centeraddress + "</td><td id='details'>" + txtDetails.value + "</td><td><a href='#' onclick='EditRecord(this)'>Edit</a></td><td><a href='#' onclick='DeleteRecord(this)'>Delete</a></td><td class='modified'>3</td></tr>");
```

I have the value of attribute classname = "modified "
The white space is a killer. I have checke my html code it doesnt have a space anywhere near the classname.

Comment: The good thing is it doesn't matter :)

Comment: Please do yourself and everyone here a favour and read - [Writing the perfect question](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) before asking more questions here.

Comment: Ok buddy. I have edited my question and been more accurate.

Comment: All you posted was code that tries to use the bad markup. I am assuming the space is there when you "view source" - if that's the case, how is the HTML created? That would be the relevant code, not what you posted.

Comment: OK I have further edited the question. I am using Jquery to append rows in my centertable. Classname modified is without any space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`hasClass` method](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) instead, then it doesn't matter if there are extra spaces:

```
if ($(collection[i]).hasClass("modified")) {
```

Comment: Well Done Buddy.... That solved the problem. You rock!